# PhpStorm "java.ioException, cant copy ..... to ......" Error

Tags: php, xampp, java-io, phpstorm-2017.2

I am using Linux Mint. In PhpStorm, I write my php code and save it to xampp/htdocs/dashboard/ to open it integrated with xampp. There is no problem when i do this in another text editor. But when I save the file to there, an error is popping up.

java.io.IOException: Couldn't copy [/home/eymen/PhpstormProjects/xampp.php/dene.php] to [/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/dene.php]

this is the error. Again, when i do the exact same thing in Sublime Text,that is not happening.